# 462 MHz UHF Narrow band FM (FRS) Receiver IC

Tags: rf

Anyone know of an IC I can use to receive signals from FRS/GPRS radios (462 MHz) FM? Most of the stuff I can find are either *transceivers* (which I don't need to transmit) - or different frequencies altogether.

I'm a strictly digital guy - so going a bit outside my comfort zone.

Comment: what's wrong with using the transceiver in rx only mode?

Comment: I guess I could - though I'm not actually sure I found one that would work with FRS frequencies. It really needs to be *small*, *simple* and low power.

Comment: Is it the SA58646 from NXP?

Comment: That's 900 MHz.

Comment: I do apologize - I thought I'd read it worked in the low UHF range too.

Comment: The TI CC1200 and CC1101 chips work at this band, however, the reference designs are for 433MHz, you will have to adjust them to fit your application.

Comment: Oohh...I think I may even have a CC1101 already layed-out for my Adruino... :-O

Answer (score 1):

Old FRS radios use a PLL synthesizer and single chip receiver the common chip used was NJM2592 made japan radio corp (link pasted below). You need a few support components like a phase shifter cap/LC and ceramic filter of the FRS bandwidth. It only needs an LC filter input and use the correct impedance conversion and you have a very cheap receiver. This is a design spin off the old motorola MC3357 & MC3362 that was the staple of old two way radios.

http://www.njr.com/semicon/products/NJM2592.html

http://www.njr.com/semicon/PDF/NJM2592_E.pdf

Comment: It should resolve your power budget, and even lower power drain if you use overtone crystals. It has audio and fsk output for data and useful for tone detection. Good luck!